# Por que sale: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic

Estoy creando una app en Ionic y al momento de guardar los datos en Firebase tengo el seguiente problema: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined. El error sale en:

```
  expedienteListRef: AngularFireList<any>;
  expedienteRef: AngularFireObject<any>;

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  //Crear en la bd
  crearExpediente(apt: Appointment) {

    return this.expedienteListRef.push({ //El error sale en esta linea
      dato1: apt.dato1,
      dato2: apt.dato2,
      dato3: apt.dato3,
      dato4: apt.dato4
    })
  }
```

La funcion deberia recuperar los datos que le envio desde el formulario con esta otra funcion:

```
formSubmit() {  //Esta es la funcion que obtiene los datos del formulario
    if(!this.expedienteForm.valid) {
      return false;
    }
    else {
      console.log(this.expedienteForm.value);
      this.aptService.crearExpediente(this.expedienteForm.value).then(res => { //aqui se envian los datos
        console.log(res)
        this.expedienteForm.reset();
        this.router.navigate(['/home']);
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }
  }
```

Los datos del formulario se obtienen correctamente, pero el problema es cuando se intenta enviarlos a la funcion 
crearExpediente(). Cual podria ser el error?

Comment: Nunca he usado AngularFileList ni AngularFireObject, por lo que no se que metodos tienen ambos objetos, sin embargo lo que si te puedo decir, es que si AngularFileList funciona igual que un FileList en javascript, entonces quiere decir que AngularFileList no es directamente pushable (es solo de lectura), ademas algo que te ayudara bastante a entender tu problema es que realmente nunca estas asignando algo a expedienteListRef ni tampoco a expedienteRef, solo los estas declarando, mas no los estas igualando a nada, es por eso que te da el error cannot read property of undefined.

Comment: Esto porque el valor por defecto de cualquier cosa a la que no le asignas nada es undefined, (debes primero asignarle algo tanto a expedienteListRef como a expedienteRef en el constructor o directamente).

Comment: Gracias por la explicación, efectivamente habia que inicializarlo en el constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto se debe a que `this.expedienteListRef` no es un arreglo.
Intenta de esta manera

```
this.expedienteListRef.set(_id, {
   dato1: apt.dato1,
   // ...
});
```

Comment: Lo intente de esa forma pero da el mismo error ahora con set: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined

Comment: Intenta inicializar primero en el metodo constructor this.expedienteListRef = this.db.list('/lists'); y luego si puedes hacer el push y el set

Comment: Si solo faltaba inicializarlo en el constructor. Gracias :)

Comment: Con gusto Daniel!